# Does the OpenStack Horizon user-interface communicate with OpenStack through the REST API only?

Tags: openstack

How does OpenStack Horizon communicate with OpenStack? Is it through the OpenStack REST API only? Or is it through function calls?

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/horizon/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenStack services can only be visited via REST API IIUC. Horizon can be installed in a dedicate node which isolated with other services.

Even there are some command line tools, but they are provided for cloud administrators and developers (they can only be invoked locally), not for normal users.

Comment: So the answer is that it only communicates through the REST API with OpenStack? seems to be your answer?

Answer (score 0):

It only communicates using RESTful calls, and mostly on HTTP (Non-Secure).